# Cinemachine Camera Shaking When Using Camera Follow

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, camera

My Cinemachine camera shakes when i use its built in camera follow system. And I know its cinemachine because if I disable the camera follow, everything works fine. this is the code for my player movement

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MousePos = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        MouseRot = MousePos - rb.position;
        MouseAngle = Mathf.Atan2(MouseRot.y, MouseRot.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 180;
        rb.rotation = MouseAngle;
        if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == 1)
        {
            Move(Accelaration, Deccelaration, MaxSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void Move(float acceleration, float deceleration, float maxSpeed)
    {
        rb.AddForce(acceleration * MouseRot.normalized);
        float SpeedVector = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.y, 2));
        rb.velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, maxSpeed);
    }
```

I tried changing the player movement script, and I also tried changing some settings on the cinemachine camera and it helped, but did not fix the issue.

Comment: Post a video of the problem so we can understand what you mean by shake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good chance that it's because you're mixing Cinemachine's normal update method and Unity physics-related update method.

[image]

In the image above, you can clearly see that sometimes the Main frame will have to reuse a Physics frame because the update rates of Main and Physics are different. That frame being reused could be the cause of your jitter problem.

**Solving this problem requires you to either (or both):**

1. Modify your camera so that it only renders the Physics frames. This way, there's no chance that your camera will render the same frame 2 times. Read more about this [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/help-my-cinemachine-is-tracking-my-player-with-jitter.1233139/).

[image]

2. Force your Rigidbody to interpolate/extrapolate between the Main frames. This way, whenever your camera request the positional values of your Rigidbody, instead of returning the values from the nearest Physics frame (which will be snappy/jittery), it will return smoothed/predicted values. Read more about this [here](https://blog.terresquall.com/2020/08/unity-rigidbodys-interpolate-property/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disable the y Axis recentering. Thats should do IT. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEOtM.jpg)